# Reading continuous message from Socket

Tags: c#, sockets

My goal is to read messages from a socket, where each message is separated with an ETX char. It is a high frequency market data feed so I don't think byte by byte approach makes sense, also the size of full message is unknown.

Is there a way I can read this message by using `NetworkStream` class? I have also tried using `Socket` class for this purpose but instead of reading messages one by one from socket it reads all messages from socket and that becomes a problem as the system slows down.

Comment: I added an example implementation in a new answer

Comment: Thanks for the help Marc. Your Answers were quite helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we go; here's the *basic* process for reading a sentinel delimited message list from a source such as a `Socket` or `Stream`. The tricky bit is keeping track of what you've used in the *incoming* buffer, and any backlog of unused data from earlier buffers. Note that changing this code between `Socket` and `Stream` is essentially changing `Receive` to `Read` - other than that the approach would be identical.

The following should basically do what you need. You can either use the `ReadNext()` API until you get a `null` (which signifies the end of the stream), or you can use `ReadAll()` which gives you an `IEnumerable<string>` sequence. The encoding and buffer-size are available for you to tweak via the constructor, but default to sane values.

```
foreach (var s in reader.ReadAll())
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

code:

```
class EtxReader : IDisposable
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ReadAll()
    {
        string s;
        while ((s = ReadNext()) != null) yield return s;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (socket != null) socket.Dispose();
        socket = null;
        if (backlog != null) backlog.Dispose();
        backlog = null;
        buffer = null;
        encoding = null;
    }
    public EtxReader(Socket socket, Encoding encoding = null, int bufferSize = 4096)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        this.buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    }
    private Encoding encoding;
    private Socket socket;
    int index, count;
    byte[] buffer;
    private bool ReadMore()
    {
        index = count = 0;
        int bytes = socket.Receive(buffer);
        if (bytes > 0)
        {
            count = bytes;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public const byte ETX = 3;
    private MemoryStream backlog = new MemoryStream();
    public string ReadNext()
    {
        string s;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            if (!ReadMore()) return null;
        }
        // at this point, we expect there to be *some* data;
        // this may or may not include the ETX terminator
        var etxIndex = Array.IndexOf(buffer, ETX, index);
        if (etxIndex >= 0)
        {
            // found another message in the existing buffer
            int len = etxIndex - index;
            s = encoding.GetString(buffer, index, len);
            index = etxIndex + 1;
            count -= (len + 1);
            return s;
        }
        // no ETX in the buffer, so we'll need to fetch more data;
        // buffer the unconsumed data that we have
        backlog.SetLength(0);
        backlog.Write(buffer, index, count);

        bool haveEtx;
        do
        {
            if (!ReadMore())
            {
                // we had unused data; this must signal an error
                throw new EndOfStreamException();
            }
            etxIndex = Array.IndexOf(buffer, ETX, index);
            haveEtx = etxIndex >= 0;
            if (!haveEtx)
            {
                // keep buffering
                backlog.Write(buffer, index, count);
            }

        } while (!haveEtx);

        // now we have some data in the backlog, and the ETX in the buffer;
        // for convenience, copy the rest of the next message into
        // the backlog
        backlog.Write(buffer, 0, etxIndex);
        s = encoding.GetString(backlog.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)backlog.Length);
        index = etxIndex + 1;
        count -= (etxIndex + 1);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something's buggy) `count` variable must be passed to each of `Array.IndexOf` methods as last parameter, otherwise it is possible to accidentally detect ETX entries in `buffer` data that was acquired turns ago and... crash

Answer (score 2):

This is presumably a text-based API, then. There is no practical difference here between using a `NetworkStream` vs a `Socket`; neither `Stream` nor `Socket` is going to "read all messages" - it is only *your code* that does that.

In both cases you will need a *virtually identical* loop which fetches the next chunk of data (which is not synonymous with a "message"), and starts looking for your sentinel value (do you mean `ETX`?) - processing or buffering as needed. Unless you know that the incoming feed is in a single-byte encoding, you would probably be best to treat it as just bytes until you have actually split it into logical messages, and *only then* run a text decoder on it to get the text of this message, before moving onto the next.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into asynchronous communication and the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) class. My approach would be:

1. Create the listener
2. Have it listen for connections continuously (`BeginAccept`/`EndAccecpt`).
3. For each connection, read asynchronously from the `NetworkStream` until the client disconnects (`BeginRead`/`EndRead`). You can read chunks of data, for example you can try to read 512 bytes at once - if there are less than 512 bytes in the buffer, you'll get less than 512 bytes.
4. Have whatever comes in appended to a `StringBuilder` (one for each connection, mind the correct encoding when converting `byte[]` to `string`)
5. If the `StringBuilder` contains the separator, split that message off and write it into a queue (don't forget to lock the queue before enqueueing!)
6. Have a separate thread continually monitor that queue for new messages and handle them. You could also signal the thread if you put something new into the queue using for example a `ManualResetEvent`.

This is only a rough outline, but I'm sure you get the idea.

There's no such thing as reading "messages" - everything that comes in via TCP/IP is just a stream of bytes - that's why you get a network *stream*. A message is a concept that you invent to interpret the data coming in.

Comment: None of the core of this, however, depends on any particular implementation; the same would apply whether using `Socket`, `Stream`, or a `TcpListener`.

Comment: You also need to be very careful about how you switch between bytes and characters; if you aren't using a single-byte encoding, it can be disastrous to do the decode before you know you have a valid string - you could have a single character split between multiple calls to "read"

Comment: Yes, that is true. The question was whether it was possible to do that using a `NetworkStream`. And as I am a fan of using higher level APIs I suggested the `TcpListener` over the `Socket` class. About the encoding: He wants to use `ETX` as a separator - how would that be encoded in a mutlibyte encoding? (personal interest question)

Comment: Well, in UTF-8, it would be encoded simply as 0x03 - but some of the **other** characters in the same stream could be two, three, etc bytes - my point wasn't about how to find the ends - it was about using `StringBuilder` in the middle. I would expect to see just a backlog of bytes (not characters), and then just run `Encoding.GetString` on them when the message bounds are known